# glibc compilation error: undefined reference to `__lll_lock_wait_private'

Tags: glibc

I got an error when compiling glibc and googled it for a long time and didn't get it! This is the output of the compiler:

```
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared -o /mnt/g/gcc/build/build-glibc-2.35/elf/ld.so.new           \
          -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,-z,defs       \
          /mnt/g/gcc/build/build-glibc-2.35/elf/librtld.os -Wl,--version-script=/mnt/g/gcc/build/build-glibc-2.35/ld.ma\
          -Wl,-soname=ld-linux-x86-64.so.2                      \
          -Wl,-defsym=_begin=0
/usr/sbin/ld: /mnt/g/gcc/build/build-glibc-2.35/elf/librtld.os: in function `_dl_make_stacks_executable':
/mnt/g/gcc/build/glibc-2.35/elf/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/dl-execstack.c:69: undefined reference to `__lll_lock_wait_private'
/usr/sbin/ld: /mnt/g/gcc/build/glibc-2.35/elf/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/dl-execstack.c:91: undefined reference to `__lll_lock_wake_private'
/usr/sbin/ld: /mnt/g/gcc/build/build-glibc-2.35/elf/librtld.os: in function `__thread_gscope_wait':
/mnt/g/gcc/build/glibc-2.35/elf/../sysdeps/nptl/dl-thread_gscope_wait.c:79: undefined reference to `__lll_lock_wake_private'
/usr/sbin/ld: /mnt/g/gcc/build/glibc-2.35/elf/../sysdeps/nptl/dl-thread_gscope_wait.c:28: undefined reference to `__lll_lock_wait_private'
/usr/sbin/ld: /mnt/g/gcc/build/build-glibc-2.35/elf/librtld.os: in function `_dl_init_static_tls':
/mnt/g/gcc/build/glibc-2.35/elf/../elf/dl-tls.c:1092: undefined reference to `__lll_lock_wait_private'
/usr/sbin/ld: /mnt/g/gcc/build/glibc-2.35/elf/../elf/dl-tls.c:1103: undefined reference to `__lll_lock_wake_private'
```

Comment: I just got the same error. Did you find a way out of this?

Comment: Same here; wondering what version of linux you're on? 22.04 here.

Comment: I ran into this issue when cross-compiling glibc in MSYS2 on Windows, targeting x86_64-pc-linux-gnu. Solved by enabling case sensitivity in my build directory (Windows file paths are case insensitive by default). Not marking this as an answer, since other folks seem to be seeing this on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I met same issue and I think I might found the root cause. I guess you are using WSL, and Windows FS is case insensitive while linux/unix is case sensitive. check this link to enable case sensitivity of your source folder, and try to re-make : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity.